# Java: Deserialize nested JSON of unknown spec to a polymorphic Hashtable

Tags: java, json, gson, moshi

I would like to convert nested JSON map with unknown/varied field names and structure to a generic & polymorphic Java data structure. I believe a `HashMap<String,Object>` encompasses this requirement for my case.

**Clarification**: polymorphic means String, HashMap or ArrayList ONLY.

Here is an example JSON, please  note that key-names and structure are variable:

```
{"k1":{"k2":["1","2"], "k3":{"k4":"v4","k5":"v5"}, "k6":"v6"}
```

I have implemented it with Gson which worked in creating the nested Java hashmap, but it tried to convert values into Java basic classes, e.g. Double, Integer etc. which not only it did it very badly (e.g. timestamp long to Double) but it was unnecessary because all I needed was to convert all values to String unless they are maps or arrays. I guess that `Object` was taken too liberally. I used this:

```
@SerializedName("data")
HashMap<String,Object> data;
```

I have asked a question about this here [Retrofit2, Gson, Java: Parse received JSON values as String, only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66876966/retrofit2-gson-java-parse-received-json-values-as-string-only) which collected negative votes but not a modicum of wisdom.

Now I am giving a try with Moshi with something like:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
public HashMap<String, Object> data;
```

but still no joy as it complains that `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter ...`

So, I am looking for guidance on this issue. I am easy, I have no need for converting JSON to POJOs. For this instance converting JSON to `HashMap<String,Object>` is enough. I am easy on the tool to use: Gson, Moshi or my own custom-made JSON -> nested polymorphic HashMap. Any pointers or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gson it's not possible to override the `Object` type adapter, so there is no a direct way to deserialize strings, lists and maps under the common type. However, you can pretend they three can have a common super type cheating the type system by introducing a marker type, for example an annotation that only marks something to have in common. The fake common type marker will only work for the top-level `fromJson` call and won't work for really strongly typed fields, however you don't need them as you mentioned in your question.

```java
@Target({})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Poly {
}
```

```java
public final class PolyTypeAdapterFactory
        implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    private static final TypeAdapterFactory defaultInstance = new PolyTypeAdapterFactory(ArrayList::new, LinkedHashMap::new);

    private final Supplier<? extends List<? super Object>> createList;
    private final Supplier<? extends Map<String, ? super Object>> createMap;

    private PolyTypeAdapterFactory(final Supplier<? extends List<? super Object>> createList, final Supplier<? extends Map<String, ? super Object>> createMap) {
        this.createList = createList;
        this.createMap = createMap;
    }

    public static TypeAdapterFactory getDefaultInstance() {
        return defaultInstance;
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(final Gson gson, final TypeToken<T> typeToken) {
        if ( typeToken.getRawType() != Poly.class ) {
            return null;
        }
        final TypeAdapter<Object> polyTypeAdapter = new TypeAdapter<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void write(final JsonWriter out, final Object o) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }

            @Override
            public Object read(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                final JsonToken token = in.peek();
                switch ( token ) {
                case BEGIN_ARRAY:
                    return readList(in);
                case BEGIN_OBJECT:
                    return readMap(in);
                case STRING:
                case NUMBER:
                case BOOLEAN:
                    return readString(in);
                case NULL:
                    return readNull(in);
                case NAME:
                case END_ARRAY:
                case END_OBJECT:
                    throw new AssertionError("Unexpected token: " + token + " at " + in);
                case END_DOCUMENT:
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError(token);
                }
            }

            @Nullable
            private Object readNull(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                in.nextNull();
                return null;
            }

            private String readString(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                return in.nextString();
            }

            private Map<String, Object> readMap(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                in.beginObject();
                final Map<String, Object> map = createMap.get();
                while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                    final String key = in.nextName();
                    if ( map.containsKey(key) ) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate key: " + key);
                    }
                    @Nullable
                    final Object value = read(in);
                    if ( value != null ) {
                        map.put(key, value);
                    }
                }
                in.endObject();
                return map;
            }

            private List<Object> readList(final JsonReader in)
                    throws IOException {
                in.beginArray();
                final List<Object> list = createList.get();
                while ( in.hasNext() ) {
                    final Object element = read(in);
                    list.add(element);
                }
                in.endArray();
                return list;
            }
        }
                .nullSafe();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        final TypeAdapter<T> typeAdapter = (TypeAdapter<T>) polyTypeAdapter;
        return typeAdapter;
    }

}
```

The type adapter above checks if the given type is the fake super type and then deserializes to three types depending on actual JSON tokens:

- primitive strings for every simple literal (Gson `nextString` coerces numbers and booleans);
- maps and lists for containers, recursively.

I slightly modified your JSON to show that numbers will be coerced to strings:

```json
{
    "k1": {
        "k2": [
            "1",
            2
        ],
        "k3": {
            "k4": "v4",
            "k5": "v5"
        },
        "k6": "v6"
    }
}
```

The following test will pass:

```java
public final class PolyTypeAdapterFactoryTest {

    private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .disableHtmlEscaping()
            .disableInnerClassSerialization()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(PolyTypeAdapterFactory.getDefaultInstance())
            .create();

    @Test
    public void test()
            throws IOException {
        try ( final JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(...) ) {
            // This is where cheating happens: we tell Gson to apply the Poly handler,
            // but it returns a Map. Well, let it be for the top-most level...
            final Map<String, ?> actual = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Poly.class);
            final Map<String, ?> expected = ImmutableMap.of(
                    "k1", ImmutableMap.of(
                            "k2", ImmutableList.of("1", "2"),
                            "k3", ImmutableMap.of(
                                    "k4", "v4",
                                    "k5", "v5"
                            ),
                            "k6", "v6"
                    )
            );
            Assertions.assertEquals(expected, actual);
        }
    }

}
```

#### No Gson but `org.json` solution

As I mentioned in the comments, you can avoid using Gson de/serialization facilities, and deserialize the given JSON fully manually:

```java
public final class OrgJsonPolyReader {

    private OrgJsonPolyReader() {
    }

    @Nullable
    public static Object read(final JSONTokener jsonTokener) {
        return read(jsonTokener, ArrayList::new, LinkedHashMap::new);
    }

    @Nullable
    public static Object read(final JSONTokener jsonTokener, final Supplier<? extends List<? super Object>> createList,
            final Supplier<? extends Map<? super String, ? super Object>> createMap) {
        while ( jsonTokener.more() ) {
            final char token = jsonTokener.nextClean();
            switch ( token ) {
            case 'n':
                jsonTokener.back();
                return readNull(jsonTokener);
            case 'f':
            case 't':
            case '0':
            case '1':
            case '2':
            case '3':
            case '4':
            case '5':
            case '6':
            case '7':
            case '8':
            case '9':
                jsonTokener.back();
                return readLiteral(jsonTokener);
            case '"':
                jsonTokener.back();
                return readString(jsonTokener);
            case '[':
                jsonTokener.back();
                return readList(jsonTokener, createList, createMap);
            case '{':
                jsonTokener.back();
                return readMap(jsonTokener, createList, createMap);
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected token: " + token);
            }
        }
        throw new AssertionError();
    }

    @Nullable
    private static <T> T readNull(final JSONTokener jsonTokener) {
        final Object value = jsonTokener.nextValue();
        assert value.equals(JSONObject.NULL);
        return null;
    }

    private static String readLiteral(final JSONTokener jsonTokener) {
        return jsonTokener.nextValue().toString();
    }

    private static String readString(final JSONTokener jsonTokener) {
        jsonTokener.next('"');
        return jsonTokener.nextString('"');
    }

    private static List<Object> readList(final JSONTokener jsonTokener, final Supplier<? extends List<? super Object>> createList,
            final Supplier<? extends Map<? super String, ? super Object>> createMap) {
        jsonTokener.next('[');
        final List<? super Object> list = createList.get();
        for ( ; ; ) {
            final char token = jsonTokener.nextClean();
            switch ( token ) {
            case ']':
                return list;
            case ',':
                break;
            default:
                jsonTokener.back();
                final Object value = read(jsonTokener, createList, createMap);
                list.add(value);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static Map<? super String, Object> readMap(final JSONTokener jsonTokener, final Supplier<? extends List<? super Object>> createList,
            final Supplier<? extends Map<? super String, ? super Object>> createMap) {
        jsonTokener.next('{');
        final Map<? super String, ? super Object> map = createMap.get();
        for ( ; ; ) {
            final char token = jsonTokener.nextClean();
            switch ( token ) {
            case '}':
                return map;
            case ',':
                break;
            case '"':
                final String key = jsonTokener.nextString(token);
                if ( map.containsKey(key) ) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicate key: " + key);
                }
                jsonTokener.next(':');
                final Object value = read(jsonTokener, createList, createMap);
                map.put(key, value);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected token: " + token);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is how it can be added to Retrofit instead of the Gson converter factory:

```java
.addConverterFactory(new Converter.Factory() {
    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(final Type type, final Annotation[] annotations, final Retrofit retrofit) {
        return responseBody -> {
            try ( final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(responseBody.byteStream()) ) {
                return OrgJsonPolyReader.read(new JSONTokener(reader));
            }
        };
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @fluffy! That's very helpful for me. Quick questions: 1) Can Moshi do this kind of thing (as I am already using Retrofit2 and perhaps I can gain some speed using Moshi) ? 2) Given that my case is simple, do you think it will run faster (android) if I implement my own JSON deserialiser (for this case only) with a standard JSON library (perhaps a naive question, sorry)

Comment: @bliako 1) Probably, I never used Moshi, so I can't tell. 2) I believe it depends on many factors: at least the performance of the JSON parser you're going to use (including special stuff like reading numbers as strings if it's supported), the way you read JSON stream and deserialize the tokens into objects, etc. In principle, you can deserialize even without Gson type adapters just converting JSON streams directly (so that no "Poly" hacks are necessary) by using low level org.json if it's flexible enough. I guess the performance difference will be too small therefore insignificant.

Comment: Thank you @fluffy, for this second part with the custom-made org.json solution. I can now see where in the ConverterFactory I can return even a custom made Response object constructed from the HashMap parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Phew, it has been a long trip. Hopefully this will help people who want to avoid using `Gson` or `Moshi` and have a simple JSON parser to convert a JSON string to a polymorphic (multi-type?) `LinkedHashMap`. Polymorphic in the sense that it contains only `String`, `Array` and `Map`. I personally prefer that than a multitude of POJOs. @Fluffy above demonstrates how to use `Gson` to create said polymorphic Map. But it is also tempting to remove `Gson` all together and use `org.json`. @Fluffy provided that solution as well.

So, again, this solution is based on @Fluffy's answer above but I have also added creating a custom object constructed on the returned Map (so that I don't keep typecasting certain  fields). I have just modified this method (`BaseResponse3` is my container class):

```
    public static Object read(final JSONTokener jsonTokener) {
        Log.d(TAG, "read()/1 : called ...");
        Map<? super String, ? super Object> ret = (Map) (read(
                jsonTokener, ArrayList::new, LinkedHashMap::new
        ));
        BaseResponse3 br = new BaseResponse3(
                Integer.parseInt((String )(ret.get("status"))),
                (String )(ret.get("message")),
                (HashMap)(ret.get("data"))
        );
        Log.d(TAG, "EOF reached: " + br);
        return br;
    }
```

The second thing I dealt with was to use this code in ... android. Ouch. It seems android has builtin `json.org` support with same namespace. And it's somewhat modified. For example it does not have the `JSONTokener(Reader ...)` constructor. Here is a question I posted regarding that: [org.json.JSONTokener : no constructor from Reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67021801/org-json-jsontokener-no-constructor-from-reader)

And so I had to use a "real" `org.json` (in my case https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) which I had to modify its namespace to `org.json.XYZ` and create a JAR (with a little help from my linux friend to automate everything). That JAR is included in Android Studio by means of adding this to `build.gradle` (Project):

```
        flatDir {
            dirs '../../3rdparty/jars'
        }
```

and this to `build.gradle` (App):

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '../../3rdparty/jars')
```

I am now incorporating this JSON parser into Retrofit as per @Fluffy's instructions using:

```
        Retrofit myRetrofitWithJsonOrg = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(base_url)
                .client(myOkHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(
                        new Converter.Factory() {
                            @Override
                            public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(final Type type, final Annotation[] annotations, final Retrofit retrofit) {
                                return responseBody -> {
                                    try (final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(responseBody.byteStream())) {
                                        return OrgJsonDeserializer.read(new org.json.XYZ.JSONTokener(reader));
                                    }
                                };
                            }
                        })
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava3CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

And all works fine.

Although there could well be performance issues (*which I have not noticed at all so far*) because Android's `org.json` may be somehow modified to handle the JSON data stream more efficiently than the vanilla `org.json`. Or `Gson` to interact with OkHttp more efficiently. I am just glad I have escaped from the claws of another dependency which I had hard time telling it how I wanted it to behave. For example, I had not managed to tell it to *^&^%&* stop converting each JSON string to Java basic types. And I ended in the ridiculous state of having integers converted to floats and timestamps (long) to ... Double!!!!! With `org.json` I am fully in control. Thanks @Fluffy.